# PushWoosh remote API createMessage limit

Tags: api, push-notification, limit, pushwoosh

Does anyone know how many notifications we can create at once using PushWoosh's remote API ?

I'm talking about this method : 
http://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/pushwoosh-push-notification-remote-api/#PushserviceAPI-Method-messages-create
Is there any limit in the "notifications" array?

I assume there must be one, but didn't find any information about it on the guides.

Thanks.

Answer : I did some testing using the Remote API, and i couldn't get a response when sending 1000 push at a time.
However, when sending 100 push, it works fine.
I would suggest sending no more than 100 (that's what i will do).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though it is possible to include several notifications in one call, I would recommend using one API call per notification. This way you can track each notification status.

Pushwoosh team :)